# Ploty Express Not Reflecting Legend / Scale on Map

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am working on composing maps with Plotly in Jupyter Notebook and most are working, but on some, it is not displaying properly - see photo.

I cannot seem to find out why it is not displaying or how to resolve it.

[image: image of Plotly map without a scale on the right side]

```
#DESTINATION Delay for each airport within a carrier network plotted on map
airline_data_frames = []
airport_list = df['DEST_AIRPORT_ID'].tolist()
airport_set = set(airport_list)
for carrier in carrier_dict:
    cur_carrier_df = carrier_dict[carrier]
    dict_airport=get_dataframe_unique_column_DEST_AIRPORT_ID(cur_carrier_df)
    out_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["NAME", "ARR_DELAY_MEAN","PERCENT_OF_AIR_TRAFFIC",         
    "LONGITUDE","LATITUDE"])
    for name in airport_set:
        if name not in (dict_airport):
            continue
        cur_df = dict_airport[name]
        airport = cur_df['DEST_AIRPORT_ID'].iloc[0]
        dest = cur_df['DEST'].iloc[0]
        arr_delay = cur_df.ARR_DELAY.mean()
        if arr_delay < 0 :
            arr_delay=0
        length = len(cur_df)/len(cur_carrier_df) * 100
        lat, long = look_up_long_lat(dest)
        airport = cur_df['DEST_CITY_NAME'].iloc[0]
        out_df = out_df.append({"NAME": airport, "ARR_DELAY_MEAN": arr_delay,         
        "PERCENT_OF_AIR_TRAFFIC":length, 
        "LONGITUDE":long.values[0],"LATITUDE":lat.values[0]}, ignore_index=True)
    print(look_up_carrier_by_initial(carrier))
    print(out_df.describe())
    fig = px.scatter_geo(out_df, lon = 'LONGITUDE',lat = 'LATITUDE', color="ARR_DELAY_MEAN", 
    hover_name="NAME", size="PERCENT_OF_AIR_TRAFFIC",projection="albers usa",scope="USA")
    fig.show()
    fig = None
```

Answer (score 0):

In revisiting this, I found this within the Plotly documentation:

> "Most Plotly Express functions accept a color argument which
>   automatically assigns data values to discrete colors if the data is
>   non-numeric. If the data is numeric, the color will automatically be
>   considered continuous. This means that numeric strings must be parsed
>   to be used for continuous color, and conversely, numbers used as
>   category codes must be converted to strings."[link to source](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/)

I resolved it by explicitly stating that the ARR_DELAY_MEAN column was of type float when I appended a line. However, this could also be done by changing a column to numeric with the pd.to_numeric function.

My Solution:

```
 out_df = out_df.append({"NAME": airport, "ARR_DELAY_MEAN": float(arr_delay),         
        "PERCENT_OF_AIR_TRAFFIC":length, 
        "LONGITUDE":long.values[0],"LATITUDE":lat.values[0]}, 
         ignore_index=True)
```

Other Possible Solution:

```
out_df["ARR_DELAY_MEAN"] = pd.to_numeric(out_df["ARR_DELAY_MEAN"])
```